# Infinite loop in algorithm to match clocks running at different speeds

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Two clocks, which show the time in hours and minutes using the 24 hour clock, are running at different
>   speeds. Each clock is an exact number of minutes per hour fast. Both clocks start showing the same time
>   (00:00) and are checked regularly every hour (starting after one hour) according to an accurate timekeeper.
>   What time will the two clocks show on the first occasion when they are checked and show the same time?
>   NB: For this question we only care about the clocks matching when they are checked.
>   For example, suppose the first clock runs 1 minute fast (per hour) and the second clock runs 31 minutes
>   fast (per hour).
>   • When the clocks are first checked after one hour, the first clock will show 01:01 and the second clock
>   will show 01:31;
>   • When the clocks are checked after two hours, they will show 02:02 and 03:02;
>   • After 48 hours the clocks will both show 00:48.

Here is my code:

```
def add_delay(min,hash)
    hash[:minutes] = (hash[:minutes] +  min)
    if hash[:minutes] > 59 
        hash[:minutes] %= 60
        if min < 60 
            add_hour(hash)
        end
    end

    hash[:hour] += (min / 60) 
    hash
end

def add_hour(hash) 
    hash[:hour] += 1
    if hash[:hour] > 23
        hash[:hour] %= 24
    end
    hash
end

def compare(hash1,hash2)
    (hash1[:hour] == hash2[:hour]) && (hash1[:minutes] == hash2[:minutes])
end




#-------------------------------------------------------------------
first_clock = Integer(gets) rescue nil
second_clock = Integer(gets) rescue nil



#hash1 = if first_clock < 60 then {:hour => 1,:minutes => first_clock} else {:hour => 1 + (first_clock/60),:minutes => (first_clock%60)} end
#hash2 = if second_clock < 60 then {:hour => 1,:minutes => second_clock} else {:hour => 1 + (second_clock/60),:minutes => (second_clock%60)} end

hash1 = {:hour => 0, :minutes => 0}
hash2 = {:hour => 0, :minutes => 0}

begin 
    hash1 = add_hour(hash1)
    hash1 = add_delay(first_clock,hash1)
    hash2 = add_hour(hash2)
    p hash2.to_s
    hash2 = add_delay(second_clock,hash2)
    p hash2.to_s
end while !compare(hash1,hash2)

#making sure print is good
if hash1[:hour] > 9

    if hash1[:minutes] > 9
        puts hash1[:hour].to_s + ":" + hash1[:minutes].to_s
    else
        puts hash1[:hour].to_s + ":0" + hash1[:minutes].to_s
    end
else
    if hash1[:minutes] > 9
        puts "0" + hash1[:hour].to_s + ":" + hash1[:minutes].to_s
    else
        puts "0" + hash1[:hour].to_s + ":0" + hash1[:minutes].to_s
    end

end

#-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

For 1 and 31 the code runs as expected. For anything bigger, such as 5 and 100, it seems to get into an infinite loop and I don't see where the bug is. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your code**

Let's look at your code and at the same time make some small improvements.

`add_delay` takes a given number of minutes to add to the hash, after converting the number of minutes to hours and minutes and then the number of hours to the number of hours within a day. One problem is that if a clock gains more than 59 minutes per hour, you may have to increment hours by more than one. Try writing it and `add_hours` like this:

```
def add_delay(min_to_add, hash)
  mins = hash[:minutes] + min_to_add
  hrs, mins = mins.divmod 60
  hash[:minutes] = mins
  add_hours(hash, hrs)
end

def add_hours(hash, hours=1)
  hash[:hours] = (hash[:hours] + hours) % 24
end
```

We do not necessarily care what either of these methods returns, as they modify the argument `hash`.

This uses the very handy method [Fixnum#divmod](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-divmod) to convert minutes to hours and minutes.

(Aside: some Rubiests don't use `hash` as the name of a variable because it is also the name of a Ruby method.)

Next, `compare` determines if two hashes with keys `:hour` and `:minutes` are equal. Rather than checking if both the hours and minutes match, you can just see if the hashes are equal:

```
def compare(hash1, hash2)
  hash1 == hash2
end
```

Get the minutes per hour by which the clocks are fast:

```
first_clock  = Integer(gets) rescue nil
second_clock = Integer(gets) rescue nil
```

and now initialize the hashes and step by hour until a match is found, then return either hash:

```
def find_matching_time(first_clock, second_clock)
  hash1 = {:hours => 0, :minutes => 0}
  hash2 = {:hours => 0, :minutes => 0} 
  begin 
    add_delay(first_clock, hash1)
    add_hours(hash1)
    add_delay(second_clock, hash2)
    add_hours(hash2)
  end until compare(hash1, hash2)
  hash1
end
```

Let's try it:

```
find_matching_time(1, 31)
  # => {:hours=>0, :minutes=>48} 
find_matching_time(5, 100)
  #=> {:hours=>0, :minutes=>0}
find_matching_time(5, 5)
  #=> {:hours=>1, :minutes=>5} 
find_matching_time(0, 59)
  #=> {:hours=>0, :minutes=>0}
```

These results match those I obtained below with an alternative method. You do not return the number hours from the present until the times are the same, but you may not need that.

I have not identified why you were getting the infinite loop, but perhaps with this analysis you will be able to find it.

There are two other small changes I would suggest: 1) incorporating `add_hours` in `add_delay` and renaming the latter, and 2) getting rid of `compare` because it so simple and only used in one place:

```
def add_hour_and_delay(min_to_add, hash)
  mins = hash[:minutes] + min_to_add
  hrs, mins = mins.divmod 60
  hash[:minutes] = mins
  hash[:hours] = (hash[:hours] + 1 + hrs) % 24
end

def find_matching_time(first_clock, second_clock)
  hash1 = {:hours => 0, :minutes => 0}
  hash2 = {:hours => 0, :minutes => 0} 
  begin 
    add_hour_and_delay(first_clock, hash1)
    add_hour_and_delay(second_clock, hash2)
  end until hash1 == hash2
  hash1
end
```

**Alternative method**

Here's anther way to write the method. Let:

- `f0`: minutes per hour the first clock is fast
- `f1`: minutes per hour the second clock is fast

Then we can compute the next time they will show the same time as follows.

**Code**

```
MINS_PER_DAY = (24*60)

def find_matching_time(f0, f1)
  elapsed_hours = (1..Float::INFINITY).find { |i|
    (i*(60+f0)) % MINS_PER_DAY == (i*(60+f1)) % MINS_PER_DAY }
  [elapsed_hours, "%d:%02d" % ((elapsed_hours*(60+f0)) % MINS_PER_DAY).divmod(60)]
end
```

**Examples**

```
find_matching_time(1, 31)
  #=> [48, "0:48"]
```

After `48` hours both clocks will show a time of "0:48".

```
find_matching_time(5, 100)
  #=> [288, "0:00"]

find_matching_time(5, 5)
  #=> [1, "1:05"] 

find_matching_time(0, 59)
  #=> [1440, "0:00"]
```

**Explanation**

After `i` hours have elapsed, the two clocks will respectively display a time that is the following number of minutes within a day:

```
(i*(60+f0)) % MINS_PER_DAY # clock 0
(i*(60+f1)) % MINS_PER_DAY # clock 1
```

[Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) is then used to determine the first number of elapsed hours `i` when these two values are equal. We don't know how long that may take, so I've enumerated over all positive integers beginning with `1`. (I guess it could be no more than 59 hours, so I could have written `(1..n).find..` where `n` is any integer greater than `58`.) The value returned by `find` is assigned to the variable `elapsed_hours`.

Both clocks will display the same time after `elapsed_hours`, so we can compute the time either clock will show. I've chosen to do that for clock `0`. For the first example (`f0=1`, `f1=31`)

```
elapsed_hours #=> 48
```

so

```
mins_clock0_advances = elapsed_hours*(60+1)
  #=> 2928

mins_clock_advances_within_day = mins_clock0_advances % MINS_PER_DAY
 #=> 48
```

We then convert this to hours and minutes:

```
mins_clock_advances_within_day.divmod(60)
  #=> [0, 48]
```

which we can then the method [String#%](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-25) to format this result appropriately:

```
"%d:%02d" % mins_clock_advances_within_day.divmod(60)
  #=> "0:48"
```

See [Kernel#sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) for information on formatting when using `%`. In `"%02d"`, `d` is for "decimal", `2` is the field width and `0` means pad left with zeroes.

Comment: Would an over-simplification be to say that you must find the LCM of the two delays and then add that to 00:00 ?

Comment: Bula, interesting idea, but not quite right as you would need a method that determines lcm for a given modulo. Consider how you might write such a method, say `Integer#lcm_modulo`, which you'd use as follows: `(60+first_clock).lcm_modulo(60+second_clock, MINS_PER_DAY)`. It's pretty straightforward, using `Enumerable#find`. (See [Integer#lcm](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Integer.html#method-i-lcm).) Once you do so, I suggest you post an answer using it. Looks good!

Answer (score 1):

The logic in your `add_delay` function is flawed.

```
def add_delay(min,hash)
    hash[:minutes] = (hash[:minutes] +  min)
    if hash[:minutes] > 59 
        hash[:minutes] %= 60
        if min < 60 
            add_hour(hash)
        end
    end

    hash[:hour] += (min / 60) 
    hash
end
```

If `hash[:minutes]` is greater than 60, you should increment the hour no matter what. Observe that an increment less than 60 can cause the minutes to overflow.

Also, you may have to increment the hour more than once if the increment exceeds 60 minutes.

Finally, it is wrong to do `hash[:hour] += (min / 60)` because `min` is not necessarily over 60 and because you have already done `add_hour(hash)`.

Here is a corrected version of the function:

```
def add_delay(minutes, time)
    time[:minutes] += minutes
    while time[:minutes] > 59  # If the minutes overflow,
        time[:minutes] -= 60   # subtract 60 minutes and
        add_hour(time)         # increment the hour.
    end                        # Repeat as necessary.
    time
end
```

You can plug this function into your existing code. I have merely taken the liberty of renaming `min` to `minutes` and `hash` to `time` inside the function.

Comment: Can you find me an example where your method works but mine doesn't?

Comment: I am sorry but on my system, 5 and 100 doesn't work with your method either

Comment: Did you delete the old `add_delay` function? If you replace your `add_delay` with my `add_delay`, the program will work.

Comment: I'm sorry it seems i modified the code after posting the question (without remembering and plugging in your function didn't work simply because the rest of it was buggy. Yes, indeed it works and it's a much cleaner than what i imagined.

Comment: Haha, no problem. It's not too late to accept my answer.